# Scala Compiler - How to inspect symbol table?

Tags: scala, plugins, compiler-construction, scala-2.8

As far as I know, the state of compiler consists of the AST and the symbol table.  I can inspect the AST with -Xprint or -Ybrowse. How can I inspect the symbol table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the solution (code snippet included) at 
http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5763